# Did they have TV back in the ancient days?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Yeshayahu is portrayed as a newscaster (Yeshayahu 42:9):

> וַחֲדָשׁוֹת אֲנִי מַגִּיד
>
> And I tell the news.

And lest you think that T.V. disappeared after the time of Yeshayahu, he informs us in that pasuk:

> הָרִאשֹׁנוֹת הִנֵּה בָאוּ
>
> The Rishonot (wives of the Rishonim) have come (onto my news show).

Additionally, Yeshayahu 2:19 describes the mastermind behind the state-sponsored television:

> ומהדר גאונו בקומו לערץ הארץ
>
> And Mahdar-- his genius, in its height, was [used] for the channel of the land (ie. state).

However, the Gemara frequently states:

> ות.ו. לא
>
> And TV, there was not.

How is one to resolve this Kashya?

---

Parenthetically, the Torah (Shmot 27:4) informs us of an Internet of sorts:

> ועשית... רשת נחשת
>
> And you shall make... an internet of copper.

### This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).